flutter App (ios) doesn't run after installation
I'm developing a Flutter app, and it installs and runs perfectly fine when I deploy it to my mobile device directly from my development environment (like VS Code or Android Studio). However, once I stop the app and try to launch it again by tapping its icon on the home screen, the app fails to start.
What could be causing this issue, and how can I troubleshoot or resolve it?

Are you running your app on a real device or simulator?
If it is a real device, yes, you can't launch the app like that because the app stops connecting (when you stop the app) to Dart VM service like the image attached below
More info here
Just try to run on release mode flutter run --release if you would like to do that
It is fine when run on a simulator


flutter run --release was the trick. It works as a command line in VScode. To do thant via Xcode, I change the RUN schema to Release as well and solved too.

This is due to the way Flutter IDE works. App cannot be run after you disconnect it from debugging mode. However you can deploy it to Test Flight and then can run it without debugging by installing it from test flight.

That's interesting Farooq.  That is NOT the case with a normal actual Xcode app.  open Xcode, click new example project, connect phone using cable, hit "Run".  The app will be running on the phone.  Disconnect the cable, the app keeps running. Quit/restart the app using your finger on the phone, and it runs fine.

That is quite interesting then . if xcode app runs like this then there may be some command for flutter ios app , Have you tried with release

Indeed Farooq what you describe is very strange to me.  My guess is that it is running the "app" in some strange manner such as, wild guess, within a Safari web page or something, IDK.  It occurs to me that when you say "due to apple privacy" that is actually incorrect. You're completely right, but that reason is wrong.

I have made a suggested edit!  As always with suggested edits, just tap the button to unwind it or change it as you wish, Farooq!  Fascinating issue, cheers

Yes it is not privacy but flutter Thanks Fattie for edit  suggestion
